# Search unicode-characters in sql server

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I have to search all records, where the attribute BodyTxt contains the unicode `\uDE8F`

How can I use the character `\uDE8F` in a Like-Statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `charindex`

```
select * from tablename where charindex('\uDE8F',columnname)>0
```

OR use `like`

```
select * from tablename where columnname like '%\uDE8F%'
```

Comment: Thanks - but the Literal \uDE8F should be interprated as a Unicode-Character. How can I do this?

Comment: @ThomasKehl So unicode of each character will be stored in column as integer?

Comment: No, but I have the Integer-Value of the Unicode-Character which I have to search for